# Configure VMware ESXi Host to broadcast its domain name like Avahi on Linux?

Tags: networking, dns, vmware, avahi

I have a local network and I have one computer on the network running VMware ESXi. I have added `esxi.local 192.168.1.100` to `/etc/hosts` on my MacBook which allows me to manage the ESXi server via the browser at `http://esxi.local`.

In addition I have configured my VMware ESXi host to have a `hostname` of `esxi`, a domain name of `local` and a FQDN of `esxi.local`.

However, I have other computers I would also like to manage it from, also on my local network but I do not want to have to add `esxi.local 192.168.1.100` to `/etc/hosts` to every of those computers.

What I would rather do is configure the VMware ESXi host to broadcast its FQDN via service discovery on my local network via the mDNS/DNS-SD protocol suite like Avahi does on Linux?

Is this possible to configure the VMware host and/or add software to the host to have it broadcast its own FQDN on the local network, or will I need do duplicate the knowledge of its IP address and FQDN/hostname by adding a `local` zone to my DNS server on my local network and manage its IP address there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ESXi does not have built-in mDNS support. Though the OS appears to be sufficiently POSIX-like that you probably could compile and run actual avahi-daemon or another mDNS responder on it.

You can make *another host* running Avahi answer for esxi.local by adding it to the `/etc/avahi/hosts` file, with the appropriate IP address.

Setting up a local DNS zone is always an option, however, **do not use `local` for unicast DNS unless you want to break the existing mDNS setup,** as macOS will stop using .local for mDNS if it detects a conflicting unicast zone. Choose another suffix and put both of them in your "domain search" list.

If your network is currently using DHCP-integrated DNS (e.g. dnsmasq) you can tell ESXi to send its hostname as part of the DHCP lease request by setting the `/Misc/PreferredHostName` option, allowing the DHCP server to register it in local DNS service.

Comment: Great answer!  Thanks.